# Problem subdividing edge loop in a model

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, loop

I have this model of a rook (chess piece) and I want to subdivide the top edge loop, but as soon I try to do that it forms a weird curvy edge loop. I have attached the model along with the pictures below...
[image: before subdividing]

[image]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1am0JbAVkdK4IXxjiKeEJKan30a5MnJTq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it happens:**

When you subdivided the top loop, two things happened:

1. You created n-gons, which behave differently with *Subdivision*.
2. You made the loop to look more like an octagon.
   It's a real pain to repair these issues, not worth your time :).

**Smart solution** :

Use the *Screw modifier* instead:

1. Keep only one side edge of your object.
2. Add the *Screw modifier*. That way, you can adjust the number of edges to your needs.
   You can also change the number anytime you want, until you *Apply* the modifier.
   And make sure to check *Calc Order*

Add the *Subdivision modifier* after the *Screw modifier*, if you need it.

[image]

*3D view so you can see better what's going on.*

[image]

**Dumb solution**:

You can make any shape into a circle using the *To sphere* tool.
It's a very useful tool, but in this case it won't help much, because of the ngons.

[image]

Further reading:
[Screw modifier in Blender Manual.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html)

Comment: Speculate that the idea of subdividing the top loop is a step towards creating  the battlements (top of castle wall) for the rook.

Comment: Sure :). But in any case, subdividing only the top loop creates n-gons, which mess up the topology, right? The screw modifier can of course be applied, before adding the battlements.

Comment: Thanx a lot! I did try the "to sphere" option before but it did not yield the result I wanted, I ended up with the same curvy mess. But the screw modifier seems to be a really clever solution. that being said, does it mess with the subdiv mod? Also what does "Calc Order" ensure?

Comment: Hi :). Screw modifier works very well with Subdivision, I use it all the time. The *Calc order* calculates order of edges to avoid problems with normals and shading.

Comment: You can now mark the answer as accepted **✓**, for others in a similar situation.